# Tool for prepopulation SQL CE database

Tags: database, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

started recently a WP8 project which uses `LINQ to SQL` as data layer. I've finished modeling the needed domain classes and would like to populate my testing database on the emulator. I managed to download the created `SDF` file (*ISETool.exe*) my problem now: How to open this file? Are there some GUI tools to read/write this SQL CE database?

I'm using `Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone` - if this info is necessary.

Any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox, supports import from csv and SQL Server. See my blog for walkthrough.